# Parsing through object saved in session storage

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-props

So, I have assigned an object with two properties, the first one "items" is an array of objects saved in session storage

```
[{"id": 0, "name": "example"}]
```

the second one is just a string

```
"this is an example"
```

When I console.log postingItems it works properly and I find the object was merged

```
method = (e) => {
        const postingItems = Object.assign({}, {
          items: sessionStorage.getItem("items1"),
          method: sessionStorage.getItem("method")
        });
        sessionStorage.setItem("items", postingItems)
        console.log(postingItems)
  }
```

but when I save postingItems in a sessionStorage and then I console.log it shows me this on the console [Object Object]

```
sessionStorage.setItem("finalItems", postingItems);
console.log(sessionStorage.getItem(finalItems));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to stringify your object first and then parse on load/get time

```
sessionStorage.setItem("finalItems", JSON.stringify(postingItems));
console.log(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("finalItems")));
```